# Why my consult in mysql have so much lag?

Tags: mysql

Okay this is my consult in mysql data base, but it give some like .  8.1319seconds to show it, so if someone have some idea to optimized it and get it more faster, I will be so glad,thanks :)

```
SELECT o.FirstName, o.Level, o.Time, o.City
FROM `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` o
  LEFT JOIN `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` b
      ON o.FirstName = b.FirstName AND o.Points < b.Points
WHERE b.Points is NULL
ORDER BY `o`.`Points`  DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

What im getting is top 100 players order by points, withour repeat name as u can see, in the maintable already are like 3000 players, thanks.

This is my Table :

---

```
PersonID | FirstName | Level | Time | City | Points
```

---

And you can register only using your firstname(like a NickName) that can be repeated and have not asocied at some PersonID, personID, just is AUTOINCREASE with each new game, so my Consult, give me the best TOP100 players in the databaase order by points, and without repeat the same name.

Comment: Show us what `explain select...` for the above query shows. Add that into the question.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: €100 that there is no index on `FirstName`

Comment: what is the logic of of `WHERE o.Points < b.Points AND b.Points is NULL`?

Comment: Edited, you can see it , thanks

Comment: Do `create index idx_MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100_points_fn on MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100 (points, firstname);` and try the query again. Do you see any improvement?